# Armadillo: LNK error using SUPERLU library

Tags: c++, windows, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I am trying to use spsolve() in armadillo. I have built the dependent superlu in windows and linked it to armadillo. I also uncommented **#define superlu** in config file of armadillo. But when I try to use the lib in my application it gives me link error. Below is the error.

> ***Error 15 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol superlu_malloc referenced in function wrapper_superlu_malloc Error  4   error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol zgssv referenced in function wrapper_zgssv 
>   Error 8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol zgssvx referenced in
>   function wrapper_zgssvx    Error  16  error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol superlu_free referenced in function wrapper_superlu_free***

I cannot find what I am missing here. Any ways to solve this?  Thanks in advance.